# Discord Button Command

Tags: discord.js

If you click the Ask button on Discord, a modal window will appear and you will be able to enter information. The full code is below.

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("discord.js");
const { ActionRowBuilder, ButtonStyle, ButtonBuilder, MessageEmbed, ModalBuilder, TextInputBuilder, EmbedBuilder, TextInputStyle  } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("Ask")
    .setDescription("Is there a problem using it? "),
  async execute(interaction) {
    const modal = new ActionRowBuilder()
      .addComponents(
        new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId("open_modal")
        .setLabel("start")
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
      );

    await interaction.reply({
      content: "Please press the button below to start the inquiry.",
      components: [modal],
    });

    // Listen for button interactions
    const buttonCollector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({
      componentType: "BUTTON",
      time: 10 * 60 * 1000,
    });

    buttonCollector.on("collect", async (buttonInteraction) => {
      if (buttonInteraction.customId === "open_modal") {
        await buttonInteraction.deferUpdate();

        const titleRow = new MessageActionRow()
          .addComponents(
            new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId("title")
            .setLabel("Title")
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.SECONDARY)
            .setDisabled(true) // Disabling the button
          );

        const contentRow = new MessageActionRow()
          .addComponents(
            new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId("content")
            .setLabel("Content")
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.SECONDARY)
            .setDisabled(true) // Disabling the button
          );

        await interaction.followUp({
          content: "Please enter the title and content.",
          components: [titleRow, contentRow],
        });
      }
    });

    // Listen for modal submit
    const collector = await interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({
      componentType: "BUTTON",
      time: 10 * 60 * 1000,
    });

    collector.on("collect", async (buttonInteraction) => {
      if (buttonInteraction.customId === "title" || buttonInteraction.customId === "content") {
        await buttonInteraction.deferUpdate();

        const title = buttonInteraction.customId === "title";
        const message = title ? "Please enter a title." : "Please enter the contents.";

        await buttonInteraction.followUp({
          content: message,
          ephemeral: true
        });
      }
    });

    collector.on("end", async (collected, reason) => {
      if (reason === "time") {
        await interaction.followUp({
          content: "Your input has timed out.",
          ephemeral: true
        });
      } else {
        // Handle the collected data (title and content) here
        const titleButton = collected.find((button) => button.customId === "title");
        const contentButton = collected.find((button) => button.customId === "content");

        if (titleButton && contentButton) {
          // Both title and content buttons were clicked, process the input
          const title = titleButton.customId === "title";
          const content = contentButton.customId === "content";

          // You can access the interaction user and the data they provided and process it here
          const user = interaction.user;
          const titleInput = titleButton.customId === "title" ? "Title Input" : "Not Provided";
          const contentInput = contentButton.customId === "content" ? "Content Input" : "Not Provided";

          // Create and send an embed with the collected data
          const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`I got an inquiry. (${user.tag})`)
            .setDescription(`**Title : ${titleInput}\n\nContent : ${contentInput}**`)
            .setFooter(`UserID : ${user.id}`)
            .setColor("GREEN")
            .setThumbnail(user.displayAvatarURL({
              dynamic: true
            }));

          // Send the embed to a designated channel (modify this to your needs)
          const channelId = "mychannelId";
          const channel = interaction.guild.channels.cache.get(channelId);

          if (channel) {
            channel.send({
              embeds: [embed]
            });
          }

          // Reply to the user with a confirmation (you can customize this message)
          await interaction.followUp({
            content: "Your inquiry has been successfully forwarded ",
            ephemeral: true
          });
        }
      }
    });
  },
};
```

I corrected all the errors in the execution log. However, when you press the button, the modal window does not appear, and the execution error continues to appear. I want the modal window to pop up when I click the button.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Asumming that `titleRow` and `contentRow` are supposed to be part of the modal (You can't add buttons to modals.) and you're on v14:

`titleRow` and `contentRow` need to be passed into `ModalBuilder#addComponents` (which needs to be an instance of `TextInputBuilder` passed into `ActionRowBuilder#addComponents`) in your case:

```js
        const titleRow = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
                new TextInputBuilder()
                .setCustomId("title")
                .setLabel("Title")
                .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
            );

        const contentRow = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
                new TextInputBuilder()
                .setCustomId("content")
                .setLabel("Content")
                .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Paragraph)
            );

        const modal = new ModalBuilder()
            .setCustomId("modalId")
            .setTitle("Modal Title")
            .addComponents(titleRow, contentRow)

        await interaction.showModal(modal)
```

To listen for modal submit, you can use

```js
const submitted = interaction.awaitModalSubmit({
   time: 10 * 60 * 100,
}).catch((error => {
   // Catch any Errors that are thrown (e.g. if the awaitModalSubmit times out)
}

if (submitted) {
   const title = submitted.fields.getTextInputValue("title")
   const content = submitted.fields.getTextInputValie("content")
   // thus do whatever with the inputs.
}
```

You can also refer to [discord.js Guide](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/modals.html) for more information on modals